# teams meeting - How to change guest user role?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

i created a meeting where everyone was the presenter by default,add two users to the meeting (one for the organization and one for the guest)

Now, i want to set the user of the organization as a attendee, and the guest as the presenter

Here is my code, after which everyone becomes a attendee..

```
                var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
            {
                AllowedPresenters = OnlineMeetingPresenters.RoleIsPresenter,
                Participants = new MeetingParticipants()
                {
                    Attendees = new List<MeetingParticipantInfo>()
                }
            };

            var attendeeList = onlineMeeting.Participants.Attendees.ToList();
            attendeeList.Add(new MeetingParticipantInfo
            {
                Role = OnlineMeetingRole.Attendee,
                Identity = new IdentitySet { User = new Identity { Id = "organization user id" } }
            });

            onlineMeeting.Participants.Attendees = attendeeList;

            return await _GraphClient.Users["user id"].OnlineMeetings["meeting id"]
                .Request()
                .UpdateAsync(onlineMeeting);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the guest user role as presenter by following code

```
Role = OnlineMeetingRole.Presenter
```

You can get the id of guest user by following graph API.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$filter=userType eq 'guest'
```

**Guest users directly can't be made as presenters without inviting them as Guests into the organization.**

Refer to documentation [plan-for-teams-live-event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-live-events/plan-for-teams-live-events#guest-to-present)

For a guest to present in a meeting, do the following tasks:

- Add the user as a guest to a team.
- Have the user accept the guest invitation and join the team.
- Schedule the live meeting and add the guest to your event group.

Ref Doc:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/meetingparticipants?view=graph-rest-1.0
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: The guest user isn't exist in the AAD.

My scenario is as follows:
Step1: create a online meeting, set AllowedPresenters = OnlineMeetingPresenters.Everyone
Step2. Get joinWebUrl
Step3. organization user join the meeting
Step4. guest users join the meeting without login in and set a name
step5. set the user of the organization as a attendee, and the guest as the presenter